# Reading a PDF document with iText not working sometimes

Tags: java, exception, pdf, itext

I am using iText to read from a PDF doc. I am getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. The strange thing is it only happens for certain files and at certain locations in those files. I suspect it's something to do with the way the PDF is encoded at those locations but can't figure out what the problem is.

I have looked at this question [Read pdf using iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637505/read-pdf-using-itext) but he seems to have solved his problem by changing the location of this file. This is not going to work for me as I get the exception at certain locations within some files - so it's not the file itself but the page in question that is causing the exception.

The stack trace is

> *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index: 02
>       at com.lowagie.text.pdf.CMapAwareDocumentFont.decodeSingleCID(Unknown Source)
>       at com.lowagie.text.pdf.CMapAwareDocumentFont.decode(Unknown Source)
>       at com.lowagie.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.decode(Unknown Source)
>       at com.lowagie.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.displayPdfString(Unknown Source)
>       at com.lowagie.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor$ShowText.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.lowagie.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.invokeOperator(Unknown Source)
>       at com.lowagie.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.processContent(Unknown Source)
>       at com.lowagie.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(Unknown Source)
>       at com.pdfextractor.main.Extractor.main(Extractor.java:61)*

And line 61 corresponds to this line:
    **content = extractor.getTextFromPage(page);**
So it seems quite obvious that the getTextFromPage() method is not working.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    ArrayList<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
        keywords.add("location");
        keywords.add("Mass Spectrometry");  
        keywords.add("vacuole");
        keywords.add("cytosol");

    String directory = "C:/Ankur/Projects/PEB/Extractor/papers/";
    File directoryToRead = new File(directory); 
    String[] sa_filesToRead = directoryToRead.list();
    List<String> filesToRead = Arrays.asList(sa_filesToRead);

    Iterator<String> fileItr = filesToRead.iterator();
    while(fileItr.hasNext()){           

        String nextFile = fileItr.next();

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(directory+nextFile);
        int noPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        PdfTextExtractor extractor = new PdfTextExtractor(reader);

    String content=""; 
    for(int page=1;page<=noPages;page++){
        int index = 1;
        System.out.println(page);
        content = extractor.getTextFromPage(page);

        }       
    }
    }
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753752/arrayindexoutofboundsexception-not-being-caught-and-ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Java classes/libraries expect that a method like `getTextFromPage(int)` are indexed starting at 0 - meaning that `getTextFromPage(0)` should return the text from page 1, `getTextFromPage(1)` should return the text from page 2.

Your for loop that causes the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is indexed starting with 1.

Are you sure that iText's `getTextFromPage(int)` is indexed starting at 1 rather than the (almost) standard 0?

Comment: No the pages start from 1 I just verified that. And the error occurs at when page=31 and there are 39 pages, so it's really strange.

Comment: That's True. Paging Does Start From 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried posting on the very active IText mailing list?

Comment: Yep - the same question has been posted there three times and not been answered.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and it always occurred where the text contains special characters. I wonder if there is a way to work around the encoding.

(Updated)
I had this problem with com.itextpdf.itextpdf of 5.1.3 but after it's updated to 5.3.4. This problem has been fixed.