# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException not being caught and ignored

Tags: java, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to catch and ignore and ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error (basically it's not something I have control over, so I need my program to keep chugging along).

However my try/catch pair doesn't seem to catch the exception and ignore it. Hopefully you can pick out what I am doing wrong.

The exception occurs at this line

> content = extractor.getTextFromPage(page);

Here is my code:

```
for(int page=1;page<=noPages;page++){
    try{
        System.out.println(page);           
        content = extractor.getTextFromPage(page);
        }
    }   
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    System.out.println("This page  can't be read");
    }    
}
```

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index: 02
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.CMapAwareDocumentFont.decodeSingleCID(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.CMapAwareDocumentFont.decode(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.decode(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.displayPdfString(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor$ShowText.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.invokeOperator(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.processContent(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(Unknown Source)
    at com.pdfextractor.main.Extractor.main(Extractor.java:64)*

**edit:** I have put the try/catch within the for loop 
and added the stack trace 
and removed index=1

Comment: By the way the line 'int index = 1' is completely useless in this case unless you have omitted code inside the try block for posting purposes

Comment: Yes that is right, I have omitted the processing but forgot about index=1, will remove it now

Comment: you only have try inside the loop, the catch statement is outside

Comment: Duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753615/reading-a-pdf-document-with-itext-not-working-sometimes

Comment: Well that was about iText and trying to figure out what was causing the exception. This is about how do we ignore the exception given that it can't be solved.

Comment: Amazingly, iText is throwing `if (offset + len > bytes.length)
                throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid index: " + offset + len);`  , But still you can't catch this Exception. I tried `catch ( Exception e )` and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException that you put in the catch from the same package as the one being thrown? i.e. java.lang

Or perhaps catch throwable to see if that even works.

Comment: That's actually a really good question, it wasn't the case, but then I imported "import java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException;" and I still get the error. I also have "import java.io.IOException;" I am wondering if that can cause a conflict?

Comment: shouldn't.  what happened when you try-catch (Throwable t)?

Comment: Sorry was in a meeting - just tried throwable and it seems to be the best solution.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible that the code that you are calling is handling the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and printing the the stack trace on its own without rethrowing it.  If that is the case, you would not see your `System.out.println` called.

EDIT:  If you want to keep chugging along, it would be good to know that the [`PDFContentStreamProcessor#processContent`](http://www.1t3xt.com/downloads/source/?page=code&id=1409) will catch the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and then throw an instance of its [`com.lowagie.text.ExceptionConverter`](http://www.1t3xt.info/api/com/lowagie/text/ExceptionConverter.html), which is a subclass of `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Thanks I will have to do a little reading to get my head around throwing and catching but I suspect you are right. Will check it out and report back.

Comment: Was just about to suggest the same thing.  Seems like a high possibility (even if it would be a weird thing for the other component to do)

Comment: You could also try and (yuck) debug code and step into the other library (assuming you have either the source code or have a de-compiler in your IDE) and see exactly what it is doing.

Comment: Thanks akf - my java skills are unfortunately not good enough to know how to implement what you suggest in your EDIT

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is a no-brainer (after all, I'm running on 3 hours of sleep in the last 36 hours), but along the lines of what digiarnie and Ankur mentioned: have you tried simply `catch (Exception e)`?

It's definitely not ideal, since obviously it (along with the `Throwable t` suggestion) will catch every exception under the sun, not limited to `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`. Just thought idea out there if you haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using this exception, you should fix your code so that you do not go past array boundaries!

Most arrays count from 0 up to array.length-1

If you replace your for loop with this, you might this avoids the entire issue:

```
for (int page = 0;page < noPages;page++){
```

Comment: The code causing the problem is not my own and the page numbers correspond to real page numbers so they cannot be arbitrarily changed - in short I am not causing the exception but I need to handle/ignore eit

Comment: But do you know what page number causes the exception? 99% of the time you should be using less than (<) instead <= when looping through an array. Did you give that a try?

Comment: Yes tried it, the page number causing the problem is page=31 and there a total of 39 pages in the document. So in short the error is not to do witih this loop it is coming out of the code behind the getTextFromPage() method - since I only get it on some documents and at different places in each document it must have something to do with how that method works - it's part of the iText package.

Comment: Yea, I see your stack trace you just added, and clearly it is coming from the PDF API you're using. Not sure exactly why it isn't being caught. You have an extra brace in your code but that should actually be causing a compile error. I guess, if desperate, you can try catching Throwable to see if you can trap *something*

Answer (score 0):

you need the try/catch to be inside the forloop. control pops out to the try catch, the catch fires, and resumes control afterwards, but the forloop has already been terminated.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still getting the problem. Initially I had it in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int page=1;page<=noPages;page++)
    {
        try
        {
            content = extractor.getTextFromPage(page); 
            System.out.println(content);
        }
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            System.out.println("This page can't be read");
        }
    }
```

Comment: page=0 causes another error - there is no page=0 the first page is page=1. The page variable corresponds to real page numbers.

Comment: is there a count method you can call on the extractor object? Where do you get noPages from?

Comment: Yes there is other code that get's that value    int noPages = reader.getNumberOfPages(); that code works fine

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a silly question... Are you sure that the exception is thrown in the code you posted and not in a differen method?

Answer (score 0):

The program should have worked. You should give more details including your class name. You can try by catching Exception or putting a finally block with some s.o.p in it.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange - I actually had a look at itext's source in the method the exception is thrown from (CMapAwareDocumentFont.decodeSingleCID) and it looks like this:

```
 private String decodeSingleCID(byte[] bytes, int offset, int len){
        if (toUnicodeCmap != null){
            if (offset + len > bytes.length)
                throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid index: " + offset + len);
            return toUnicodeCmap.lookup(bytes, offset, len);
        }

        if (len == 1){
            return new String(cidbyte2uni, 0xff & bytes[offset], 1);
        }

        throw new Error("Multi-byte glyphs not implemented yet");
    }
```

The ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException it throws is the standard Java one. I can't see any reason your original try-catch not working.

Perhaps you should post the entire class? Also, which version of itext are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Wait a second! You're missing some braces in there :) Your catch statement is outside your for statement! You have this:

```
for(int page=1;page<=noPages;page++){
    try{
        System.out.println(page);               
        content = extractor.getTextFromPage(page);
        }
    }   
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    System.out.println("This page  can't be read");
    }    
}
```

It should be:

```
for(int page=1;page<=noPages;page++) {
    try{
        System.out.println(page);               
        content = extractor.getTextFromPage(page);
    }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("This page  can't be read");
    } 
} //end for loop  

}//This closes your method or whatever is enclosing the for loop
```

Comment: Actually, this wouldn't compile if you had it like this.