# How to extract the data from a pdf File using iText

Tags: java, itext

I am working on a program that extracts data from a PDF file and I am using iText as java library. When I try to open the file using this method :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // TODO code application logic here

        PdfReader pr=new FdfReader("C:\\Users\\saviour\\Desktop\\doc308-999.pdf");

        String str=PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(pr, 2); 
        System.out.println(str);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PDFTests.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

I have this Error:

```
com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: FDF header signature not found.
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PRTokeniser.checkFdfHeader(PRTokeniser.java:215)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.FdfReader.readPdf(FdfReader.java:95)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:169)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:158)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.FdfReader.<init>(FdfReader.java:63)
    at pdftests.PDFTests.main(PDFTests.java:39)
```

So I am asking about the purpose of this Exception :)
Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility that the pdf file you are trying to load is either not a pdf file. Or it does not contain an FDF Form. Please read javadoc on [InvalidPdfException](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/exceptions/InvalidPdfException.html).

You can try the following code change and get expected result.
Change `PdfReader pr=new FdfReader("C:\\Users\\saviour\\Desktop\\doc308-999.pdf");`
to `PdfReader pr=new PdfReader("C:\\Users\\saviour\\Desktop\\doc308-999.pdf");`

References:

- [PDFReader](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html)
- [FDFReader](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/FdfReader.html)
- [InvalidPdfException](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/exceptions/InvalidPdfException.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the file location. Sometimes OS does not allow file to be read from some system drives by other applications. Put somewhere in D: etc.

Also make sure you have sufficient pages in the PDF. (atleast 2 pages since you are reading 2nd page) or try with `parser.getTextFromPage(1)` etc. to get content from other pages.

You can have a  more look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637505/read-pdf-using-itext).